# Resuming tasks using NSURLSession when app removed from background or on device reboot

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-s3, nsurlsession, completionhandler

I have checked many docs but could not found solution for **Resuming tasks using NSURLSession** when app removed from background or on device reboot.

I am dealing with amazon S3 to upload some files, In that **I am able to**

1. **Upload file** to S3 using NSURLSessionUploadTask, when app is in foreground as well as in background.
2. **Resume task** when app **crashed** due to any other reason while uploading and if app is not removed from background.
3. **Restart task** if I **reboot device** while uploading and if app is not removed from background.

Here is my code to achive resume fuctionality written in applicationDidBecomeActive method of appdelegate.

```
// Initialize session config and the background session
NSURLSession *l_taskSession = [self backgroundSession];

[l_taskSession getTasksWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *dataTasks, NSArray *uploadTasks, NSArray *downloadTasks)
 {
     if([uploadTasks count])
     {
         for (int i=0; i<[uploadTasks count]; i++)
         {
             NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadRequestTask = (NSURLSessionUploadTask*)[uploadTasks objectAtIndex:i];
             [uploadRequestTask  resume];
             NSLog(@"-------- Upload Resumed ------- ");
         }
     }
     else if(![uploadTasks count])
     {
         NSLog(@"------- There are no previous tasks -------");
     }
 }];
```

Now the problem is in both the case (2 & 3) mentioned above it doesn't give list of tasks that were in progress, when I removed app from background and launched again, as per code it falls in else if condition and logs

2015-06-12 17:12:32.902 AppName[162:60b] ------- There are no previous tasks -------

So my **question is** this possible to resume tasks when app removed from background ? Or can anybody just give me reference links where I can find answer for the same, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this problem?

Comment: @AhadKhan not yet, Lack of documentation, I am still searching... If I found I will post here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I come to conclusion that,

If an iOS app is terminated by the system and relaunched, the app can use the same identifier to create a new configuration object and session and retrieve the status of transfers that were in progress at the time of termination. **This behavior applies only for normal termination of the app by the system.**

**If the user terminates the app from the multitasking screen, the system cancels all of the session’s background transfers.**

For more details check Apple's documentation on NSURLSessionConfiguration Class Reference [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLSessionConfiguration_class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLSessionConfiguration/backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:).